# What toString function does JSON stringify use?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create my own `toString` function for a data type.

Let's take an example:

```
JSON.stringify({}) // "{}"
```

I want `"test"` to be returned. So, I tried to modify the object prototype:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function () { return "test"; }
```

Then: `JSON.stringify({})` returns `"{}"`, too.

I am sure that there is a function that can be rewritten to return custom values.

What's that function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
   function MyObj() {};
   MyObj.prototype.toJSON = function(){return "test";}

   JSON.stringify(new MyObj())
   ""test""
```

JSON looks for `toJSON` functions on the objects it stringifies.  Notice however that you don't return a string from `toJSON`, you return an object that gets stringified in place of the object you passed in.  In this case I returned a string, so that's why the return value has extra quotes around it.

You can also do the same thing with a translation function passed to stringify.

```
var x = {};
JSON.stringify(x, function(key, value){ 
    if (value===x) {return "test";} else {return value;}
});
""test""
```

For more information on the translation function see [Using native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter).