# Json stringify javascript Object result not match

Tags: javascript, json

I want to store this object to databse,so first need to post this to backend.

```
Recorder {config: Object, recording: false, callbacks: Object, context: AudioContext, node: ScriptProcessorNode…}
```

but after `JSON.stringify(recorder)`

the result look like this

```
{"config":{"bufferLen":4096,"numChannels":2,"mimeType":"audio/wav"},"recording":false,"callbacks":{"getBuffer":[],"exportWAV":[]},"context":{},"node":{},"worker":{}}
```

why the context parts missed?

I found that because context is a nested object,so how can I using `JSON.stringify` for a nested Object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What toString function does JSON stringify use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925983/what-tostring-function-does-json-stringify-use)

Comment: What output do you get if you do a console.log of your Recorder object?
If you fully expand that object tree, what does it look like?

Comment: check `JSON.parse(new AudioContext())` - you'll see that it outputs `{}` - probably because it can't be represented as a string

Comment: I found out AudioContext is a super nest object (up to 16)
how to store this kind of nest object to database?

Answer (score 0):

> `JSON.stringify()` is compatible only with javascript object of
>   `Object()`. not a special object like I can see in your code `context:
>   AudioContext, node: ScriptProcessorNode`. If you are use
>   JSON.stringify with that object then it store only property and value,
>   not a behavior of that object

For special class of object you can use **serialijse** plugin which is available in [github](https://github.com/erossignon/serialijse)

For your solution use this plugin after download it

For convert it in string for store in database in backend

```
var serialize = serialijse.serialize;
var serializationString = serialize({config: Object, recording: false, callbacks: Object, context: AudioContext, node: ScriptProcessorNode…});
```

For convert it to original object after retrieving it from database:

```
var deserialize = serialijse.deserialize;
var deserializationString = deserialize(serializationString );
```

I hope it would be help to you.

Comment: like this?    `var serializationString = serialize(Recorder)`

Comment: import `<script src="./serialijse.bundle.js"></script>`  is good ,but still  `Uncaught ReferenceError: serialize is not defined(…)`  I thinks this module have some problem

Comment: have you try this module yourself?

Comment: I have used this earlier as I have suggested way.

Comment: do you know why it says serialize is not defined

Comment: Ohhh... I missed two line to add in my answer,
var serialize = serialijse.serialize;
var deserialize = serialijse.deserialize;

Answer (score -3):

Use JSON.parse() before converting it as a string to be passed to the database (using JSON.stringify()) and check and see you're getting the contextparts while parsing.

HTH

Comment: The aren't trying to parse anything.

Comment: use JSON.parse on what exactly?

Comment: AudioContext which he had mentioned as "context parts" in his post.