# Why does logging the same thing give 2 different outputs in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, console.log

I'm a junior developer and currently struggling with the following issue:

I have an object called **changes**, when i log changes to the console (like this):
`console.log(JSON.stringify(changes));`

I get the following:

```
{"from":{"previousValue":null,"currentValue":"2023-09-14T00:00:00+02:00","firstChange":false}}
```

So here we can see that previousValue is null and currentValue is a date

When i put (ON THE NEXT LINE):

`console.log(changes.from.previousValue);`

Then for some reason its not null, but it says `Invalid Date`, as far as I understand I'm logging the exact same thing? So why whould the output be different? Any help is much appreciated, also this is my first post ever so dont be too harsh please ;)

Even if I get an explanation about why it's not the same, I still need to access the null value, so how would i get that?

**Edit:**
The object gets populated automatically, the changes object is of type SimpleChanges, used in ngOnChanges, so I guess it's a part of angular or typescript itself

Comment: It looks like `previousValue` is an invalid date object whose [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is `NaN` which when `JSON.stringified` is `null`. When simply logging the object the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) value is used which is `Invalid Date`

Comment: The docs detail all the rules that [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) uses in serializing different values.

Comment: I stand corrected. It appears Date uses [Date#toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) directly when being stringified and this simply yields `null` bypasssing the `NaN` valueOf. (*'...A string representing the given date in the date time string format according to universal time, or null when the date is invalid.'*) Whereas the console uses `toString()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference in using toString() compared to JSON.stringify()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834172/whats-the-difference-in-using-tostring-compared-to-json-stringify)

Comment: also see: [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript) and [Difference between toJSON() and JSON.Stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734894/difference-between-tojson-and-json-stringify) and [What toString function does JSON stringify use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925983/what-tostring-function-does-json-stringify-use)

Comment: Really what I wanted to do is see if the value is null but the value was never null even though it showed so in console, therefore my confusion, i solved it by using IsNan(changes...), thanks a lot!

Comment: It's actually a Date object, just an invalid one. see: [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes this last comment of yours is the post I used to fix it, thanks so much! do you mind writing your help in a comment so that i can mark it as solved? thanks anyway

Comment: A bit of an XY Problem, but it covers a lot of general territory if you read all the related posts ;)